# How could I print the max and min values in a 2D array?

Tags: c, max, min

here is my code, it is working but it prints only the min value and prints it as negative. what is wrong with this code ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    double x[5][5],Max, Min;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<5; j++)
            scanf("%lf", &x[i][j]);
    }
    Max = x[0][0];
    Min = x[0][0];

        if (x[i][j] > x[0][0])
            printf("Max= %f\n", x[i][j]);

    else if (x[i][j] < x[0][0])
        printf("Min = %f\n", x[i][j]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not how you find the maximum. You need to compare the current version to the maximum, and if greater, set maximum to the new value, then at the end of the loop, display the maximum. Similar for the minimum. The code you wrote has major problems, for example, the `if` is outside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You never iterate through your arrays after receiving the inputs, because you are outside the `for` loops. You could do:

```
Max = x[0][0];
Min = x[0][0];

for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
    {
        if (x[i][j] < Min)   // Is current element smaller than Min?
            Min = x[i][j];        // If so, update Min
        if (x[i][j] > Max)   // Is current element greater than Max?
            Max = x[i][j];        // If so, update Max
    }
}

printf("Max= %f\n", Max);
printf("Min= %f\n", Min);
```

Comment: No particular reason, that solution would probably be slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to enclose the search of the minimum and the maximum in a loop.:)

Try the following

```
for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j<5; j++)
        scanf("%lf", &x[i][j]);
}
Max = x[0][0];
Min = x[0][0];

for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j<5; j++)
    {
        if ( Max < x[i][j] )
        {
            Max = x[i][j];
        }
        else if ( x[i][j] < Min )
        {
            Min = x[i][j];
        }
    }
}

printf( "Max = %f\n", Max );
printf( "Min = %f\n", Min );
```

Comment: Nice catch - any particular value cant be both the min _and_ the max. Except for [0][0], _if_ all elements are the same. But that's irrelevant, since we've already set both values to the one that [0][0] contains.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through all the values in the 2D array to check all the values of the 2D array and set the `max` and `min` variable accordingly:

```
    Max = x[0][0]; //set max as the first element
    Min = x[0][0];  //set min as the first element
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++) //loop through each row
    {
        for (j = 0; j<5; j++) //loop through each column
    {
            if (x[i][j] > Max) //if current value is more than max
            Max=x[i][j];
            if (x[i][j] < Min) //if current value is less than min
            Min=x[i][j];
        }
    }

    printf("Max= %f\n", Max);   
    printf("Min = %f\n", Min);
```